# How to 'require' an xml file (loaded by webpack) in order to read the xml contents in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, webpack

I'm using webpack as the bundler for a app and using an XML file for it configuration. Currently I'm writing tests to retrieve the config from an XML file packaged by webpack.

Referencing this webpack article: [Loading data](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-data) the piece of code I'm having trouble is this:

```
import Data from './data.xml';
```

I'm my own test, I'm using the *require* form which is as follows:

```
const select = require('xpath.js');
const DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser
const parser = new DOMParser();
const data = require('./app.config.xml'); // <- THIS IS MY PROBLEM
const xdocument = parser.parseFromString(data.toString(), 'text/xml');
```

How does 'require' work for an XML file?

This code:

```
console.log("DATA: " + data.toString());
```

produces this output:

```
DATA: [object Object]
```

So I don't know what object is being created by the require.

I have seen a lot of other code samples about reading xml into JSON, but I don't what to have to handle a JSON object. I want to interrogate the XML as an XMLObject so can run xpath queries against it.

I can easily, get to the JSON, by running

```
JSON.stringify(data)
```

which displays something like:

```
    {"Application":{"$":{"name":"config-data"},"Imports":[{"Import":[{"$":{"from":"./another.config.xml"}}]}],"Con

which is not what I want. So how can I get the XML content from *data* as a string, which is what **parser.parseFromString** needs?
```

My test code is as follows:

```
  describe.only('xpath examples (zenobia)', async assert => {
    const xdoc = require('./app.config.xml');

    let applicationNodes = select(xdoc, "/Application"); // THIS RETURNS a DOMObject
    console.log(`Found ${applicationNodes.length} Application elements`);

    assert({
      given: 'an inline xml document with an Application',
      should: 'Select an element from the root',
      condition: applicationNodes !== null
    });
  });
```

That log message displays:

```
Found 0 Application elements
```

for an XML document that is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Application name="app">
  <Imports/>
</Application>
```

Comment: `DATA: [object Object]` this indicates `data` is an object - so, it's probably already what you want, i.e. you don't need to parse it

Comment: Are you saying that 'data' here is the XML document then?

Comment: I'm using xpath.js to run queries (select=require('xpath.js'); const applicationNodes = select(xdoc, "/Application"); // This does not work!

Comment: I'm saying it's an object. Can you determine what type? I can't. I don't have your code

Comment: `const application-nodes` is one problem ... and where is xdoc declared

Comment: SO my question was asking, how does require work when it is loading a xml file as illustrated as an example in the webpack documentation.

Comment: again, if you read the documentation fully, `const xdoc = require('./app.config.xml');` this will not result in an xml document object, rather it will be a plain ol javascript object

Comment: So the webpack doc is wrong then?

Comment: No, it isn't wrong at all, because nowhere does the documentation state the importing an `.xml` will result in an `xml document` object - in fact it states: *Now you can import any one of those four types of data (JSON, CSV, TSV, XML) and the Data variable you import it to will contain **parsed JSON** for easy consumption* - and we all know that the result of *parsed JSON* is a plain ol' javascript Object

Comment: Yeah sorry just re-read. I still don't know how to solve this though, which is why I posted the question.

Comment: so you actually want an XMLdoc type Object? `xml-loader` uses `node-xml2js` which claims to `supports bi-directional conversion. Uses sax-js and xmlbuilder-js` - so, if you use `node-xml2js` it seems you could create the XML from the `Object` you have - seems awfully messy though I must admit, but since `xml-loader` doesn't seem to have the option to produce an "XML document  object" I can't see a way around it

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm going to start again. I misread the webpack doc. Webpack is definitely not the way to go for this. I initially thought that this would be a good way to load static XML data into my test cases, but this won't work as I need it to, since I want to run xpath queries, rather than handle a JSON blob.

Comment: JSON is  a string, not an object and not a blob :p

Comment: But you know what I mean.

Comment: yeah .. just being pedantic :p but you wont try converting the object to an xml document as I suggested?

Comment: Yeah, I will, thanks for that.

Comment: Or, use [raw-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/) for xml files - then your original code should actually work :

Comment: Ah nice. Can you reply as an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to read XML files as strings you can simply use Webpack [raw-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/) with the following configuration

```
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.xml$/i,
        use: 'raw-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Now `data` in

```
const data = require('./app.config.xml');
```

Should be the raw data from the XML file (i.e. a string) - the rest of your code should now work as expected

Comment: A small reminder, you need to execute 【npm install --save raw-loader】 in advance。